# matlab: variables in terms of functions

Tags: matlab, math

I have a problem similar to below:

```
A(n-1) = n*A(n) + A(n+1)
```

Given

```
A(20) = 0
A(19) = beta
```

Calculate `beta` if

```
A(0) = 0.5
```

So for example I'll get for

```
n = 19, A(18) = 19*beta
n = 18, A(17) = 18*19*beta - beta
```

My question is, can instead of manually expanding, can I store each `A(n)` value in a matrix in terms of beta and expand so that I get a final `A(0) = ...` some function in terms of `beta`.

Would it be possible to use anonymous functions?

Comment: Do you have the symbolic toolbox? Your stated problem and your example expansion don't match each other, btw - I presume there's a typo in one or the other.

Comment: Yeah, I can use syms to represent beta. Is it possible to solve say syms a; x = a+1; solve for a if x = 1?

Comment: Any issue with implementing this using `for` loop?

Comment: Sure.  `y = solve('x = a+1','a'); x=1; subs(y)`

Answer (score 0):

This will take you as far back as A(1).

```
syms b;
A = [repmat(0,[1,18]),b,0]

    for n = 19:-1:2
        A(n-1) = n*A(n) + A(n+1);
    end
```

Then you just need `A(1)`, `A(2)` and your already known value for `A(0)`, to create the final equation you need to `solve`/`subs`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to compute this using a variable. Since everything is linear, the sequence with A(19)=beta is the same as the sequence with A(19)=1, where then every sequence element is multiplied with beta.

Thus, compute A(0) from A(20)=0 and A(19)=1 and set beta=0.05/A(0).